# HTTP requests for real time application, performance tips

Tags: java, real-time, okhttp, http2

I'm using Java's OkHttp3 to send multiple POST requests to the same REST endpoint, which is a third party AWS server on the same region as mine. I need those requests to be processed as fast as possible (even 1ms counts).

Right now the only performance tips I'm applying are very basic: I'm using HTTP2 so the connection socket is reused and I'm sending the requests asynchronously so it doesn't wait for any response until all requests are sent.

What are other tips I should consider to improve the performance?

**EDIT:** In case this is important for any reason, I'm currently passing all params through the URL, the body of the requests is empty. I may pass them as part of the body but I arbitrarily decided not to.

Comment: Do you have to use HTTP? A text based protocol isn’t exactly what I’d choose if I was optimising for latency. Binary encoded UDP can get your latency down to nanos on a good link.

Comment: Also note that passing sensitive information in URL parameters is a very poor choice from a security standpoint.

Answer (score 0):

OkHttp is a good choice for low-latency. Netty may be a better choice for high-concurrency, but that's not your use-case.

You may want to measure what happens when you disable gzip. You’ll need to remove the `accept-encoding` request header in a network interceptor. That might make things faster since but only because you're on a fast link.

One other thing to research is disabling [Nagle’s algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle's_algorithm). You'll need to call `Socket.setTcpNoDelay()` which you can do with a custom `SocketFactory`.

The next release of OkHttp will support unencrypted HTTP/2. If you're okay with this (it is almost always a bad idea), removing TLS might buy you a (small) gain. Be very careful here; plaintext comms are bad news.

Comment: Excellent, I'll check all that. By the way, I should have added the requests are POST, but I'm currently passing all data through params in the URL (empty body). Maybe that is important for other kind of optimizations, I'll edit the question to add that info.